# how to replace vertex by another mesh?

Tags: mesh, vertices

I have (downloaded) a model, it is rigged, with weight, which (I guess) cause the mesh become some vertex group. can I replace part (or all) of the model vertex? with another mesh?

Comment: you can but the new mesh won't have the same vertex groups, unless you've created some vertex groups for this other mesh, that have the same names

Comment: so that mean I will lost all the rig, right? unless I rig it again.   I mean the vertex group is not manually grouped or named, it is (might be) automatic generated when rigged.

Comment: You can try the Data Transfer modifier with the previous object as Source, but if it doesn't work you need to parent With Automatic Weight